# Combine or merge array based on values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which gives me the order delivery date and an array of what items were on that order.

```
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 14 May, 2021
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Bestsellers Brownie Box
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 14 May, 2021
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Cookies & Cream Brownies
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 14 May, 2021
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Bestsellers Brownie Box
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 29 May, 2021
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Bestsellers Brownie Box
            )

    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 13 May, 2021
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Bestsellers Brownie Box
            )

    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 13 May, 2021
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Bestsellers Brownie Box
            )

    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => 14 May, 2021
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Bestsellers Brownie Box
            )

    )
```

What I need to do is to sort of merge this, so we end up with an array that is more like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 14 May, 2021
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 3 x Bestsellers Brownie Box
                [1] => 1 x Cookies & Cream Brownies
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 29 May, 2021
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1 x Bestsellers Brownie Box
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 13 May, 2021
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2 x Bestsellers Brownie Box
            )

    )
```

So it brings together everything that is due out for delivery on a specific day. I hope that makes sense. The plan here is to create a calendar view so that at a glance, my client can see how many items they have out for delivery on a certain day.

I just can't work out how to combine/merge/join these arrays in such a way. I have some ideas but I just think they might get quite cumbersome, and someone here is bound to have some good methods of doing this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is fairly strainght forward stuff. Have you made an attempt at coding this we can see

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I haven't done, well, I have tried a few things but I can't work out a very efficient way of doing it. Glad to hear it is straightforward, perhaps you can help me learn how to do it :) Thanks.

Comment: Before you try for efficiency or optimisation, first just get it working

Comment: I don't really know how @RiggsFolly - hence me asking the question here. I totally get your point, but I am stuck. I need help.

Comment: You simply iterate over all orders. And for each order you process you check if date and item already exists in the result, if not you create them, otherwise you increment a counter.

Comment: I understand the logic to that @arkascha - but I am struggling to see how I do it. I can obviously run a foreach on the original array. But then do I create a new array to store my new values in? I am not even sure how I'd check if a date already exists in that new array - this is my point, I am stuck and I cannot see the wood for the trees.

Comment: All these individual little tasks can be researched. When facing a problem, break it down into steps, then solve each of the steps. All of this has been well covered both on and off the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that would do what you ask:

```
<?php
$input = [
[
  "14 May, 2021",
  [ "Bestsellers Brownie Box" ] ],
[
  "14 May, 2021",
  [ "Cookies & Cream Brownies" ] ], 
  [
    "14 May, 2021",
    [ "Bestsellers Brownie Box" ] ], 
  [
    "29 May, 2021",
    [ "Bestsellers Brownie Box" ] ], 
  [
    "13 May, 2021",
    [ "Bestsellers Brownie Box" ] ], 
  [
    "13 May, 2021",
    [ "Bestsellers Brownie Box" ] ], 
  [
    "14 May, 2021",
    [ "Bestsellers Brownie Box" ] ]
];

$output = [];
array_walk($input, function($order) use (&$output) {
  $date = $order[0];
  $items = $order[1];
  
  if (!array_key_exists($date, $output)) {
    $output[$date] = [];
  }
  
  foreach ($items as $item) {
    if (array_key_exists($item, $output[$date])) {
      $output[$date][$item] += 1;
    } else {
      $output[$date][$item] = 1;
    }
  }
});

print_r($output);
```

The output obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [14 May, 2021] => Array
        (
            [Bestsellers Brownie Box] => 3
            [Cookies & Cream Brownies] => 1
        )
    [29 May, 2021] => Array
        (
            [Bestsellers Brownie Box] => 1
        )
    [13 May, 2021] => Array
        (
            [Bestsellers Brownie Box] => 2
        )
)
```

---

A variant to create exactly the format you suggested would be that:

```
<?php
$input = [
[
  "14 May, 2021",
  [ "Bestsellers Brownie Box" ] ],
[
  "14 May, 2021",
  [ "Cookies & Cream Brownies" ] ], 
  [
    "14 May, 2021",
    [ "Bestsellers Brownie Box" ] ], 
  [
    "29 May, 2021",
    [ "Bestsellers Brownie Box" ] ], 
  [
    "13 May, 2021",
    [ "Bestsellers Brownie Box" ] ], 
  [
    "13 May, 2021",
    [ "Bestsellers Brownie Box" ] ], 
  [
    "14 May, 2021",
    [ "Bestsellers Brownie Box" ] ]
];

$output = [];
array_walk($input, function($order) use (&$output) {
  $date = $order[0];
  $items = $order[1];
  
  if (!array_key_exists($date, $output)) {
    $output[$date] = [$date, []];
  }
  
  foreach ($items as $item) {
    if (array_key_exists($item, $output[$date][1])) {
      $output[$date][1][$item] += 1;
    } else {
      $output[$date][1][$item] = 1;
    }
  }
});
$output = array_values($output);

print_r($output);
```

The that output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 14 May, 2021
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Bestsellers Brownie Box] => 3
                    [Cookies & Cream Brownies] => 1
                )

        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 29 May, 2021
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Bestsellers Brownie Box] => 1
                )

        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13 May, 2021
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Bestsellers Brownie Box] => 2
                )

        )
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much - that is really helpful. I'll go through the code so I fully understand the constituent parts of it too. Much appreciated.